# remove link color and underline in pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

I have a table named sample. The table contains data within the `a href` tag.

I want to convert the table to pdf format. My code is:

```
var toPDF = function(htmlId, config ){
    if( $('#'+htmlId).length > 0)
        {
            reportParameters['reportString'] = $('#'+htmlId).html();
            reportParameters['config'] = JSON.stringify(config);
            window.open('url','Page');
        }
    else
        {
            alert('Invalid HTML ID');
        }
  };


 function myFunc()
 {
    var conf = {
        'headerCenter':'sample',
        'pageSize':'A4',
        'headerFontSize':18,
        'headerLine':true,
        'headerSpacing':2,
        'footerLine':false,
        'footerCenter':'Date: [date] [time]',
        'footerRight':'Page[page]',
        'footerFontSize':8,
        'footerSpacing':1
    }       
    toPDF('sample',conf);
}
```

The above code works fine. But my problem is, the pdf data contains the link data as blue color and underlined.

How can I remove link color and underline??

Comment: `a { text-decoration:none;color:#000;}`

Comment: What is `toPdf`? Perhaps there is documentation there

Comment: Remove it in CSS using the suggestion of madlin

Comment: @madalinivascu and Sato Where do you see CSS anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

check this both css code !!

```
a {color:black;text-decoration:none;}
a:hover{text-decoration:none;color:red;}
```